# Need help to make validation when two range contradict

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, object

I have an object name config in which i have "from" and "to".

```
const config = {
  "0": {
    id: 0,
    from: 0,
    to: 10,
    hex: null
  },
  "1": {
    id: 1,
    from: 11,
    to: 20,
    hex: null
  },
  "2": {
    id: 2,
    from: 21,
    to: 30,
    hex: null
  },
  "3": {
    id: 3,
    from: 31,
    to: 40,
    hex: null
  },
  "4": {
    id: 4,
    from: 41,
    to: 50,
    hex: null
  }
};
```

I have to check that now range will contradict with each other eg: form:0 => to:10 and from:5=> to:20
here the from of second is contradict because 5 lies between 0 to 10

i have tried following but doesn't full-fill my requirement

```
function found(conf) {
  let isFound = false;
  for (let obj in conf) {
    for (let x in conf) {
      if (
        conf[obj].id !== conf[x].id &&
        (conf[x].from >= conf[obj].from && conf[x].to <= conf[obj].from)
      ) {
        console.log(conf[obj], conf[x]);
        isFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isFound) break;
  }
  return isFound;
}
console.log(found(config));
```

Comment: the user will change the value of each from and to through input in that situation i have to check that two ranges are not contradict

Comment: Let me rephrase. Have you tried anything? SO is for problems and not for requirements. So please try to solve it and if you fail, please share that attempt so that we can help you.

Comment: Sounds like a simple double/triple loop or a reduction, where are you stuck? ps: If you use 0 to 4 as object keys, just use an array directly and save yourself a bunch of characters to type.

Comment: So... 5 would only work in the first case, why is there a contradiction? Show your work!

Comment: what i have tried is updated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a single array by combining all ranges

```
const arr = Object.entries(config).map(([a, b]) => b).flatMap(({from, to}) => RANGE(from, to))
```

where RANGE is method which return array of given ranges:

```
const RANGE = (a,b) => Array.from((function*(x,y){
      while (x <= y) yield x++;
})(a,b));
```

Then find duplicates in the given arr using the following function:

```
function findDuplicate(array) { 
    var object = {};
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function(item) {
      if (!object[item]) object[item] = 0;
      object[item] += 1;
    });
    for (var prop in object) {
      if (object[prop] >= 2) {
        result.push(prop);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }


const duplicates = findDuplicate(arr)
```

Then finally check `duplicates.length`

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming your variables so they make sense.

Your logic is: IDs don't match and inner is after outer, but before outer's from.

There will never be a case where this will return true.

```js
const config = {
  "0": { id: 0, from:  0, to: 10, hex: null },
  "1": { id: 1, from: 11, to: 20, hex: null },
  "2": { id: 2, from: 21, to: 30, hex: null },
  "3": { id: 3, from: 31, to: 40, hex: null },
  "4": { id: 4, from: 41, to: 50, hex: null }
};

console.log(found(config));

function found(conf) {
  for (let outer in conf) {
    for (let inner in conf) {
      let idsDontMatch = conf[outer].id !== conf[inner].id;
      let innerFromGteOuterFrom = conf[inner].from >= conf[outer].from;
      let innerToLteOuterFrom = conf[inner].to <= conf[outer].from;
      let innerAfterOuterButBeforeOuterFrom = innerFromGteOuterFrom && innerToLteOuterFrom;
      if (idsDontMatch && innerAfterOuterButBeforeOuterFrom) {
        console.log(conf[outer], conf[inner]);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```